# Logs on deleting a link on top navigation

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, navigation

Is there any way I can find out the link that was deleted on the top navigation of a SharePoint site collection?.

Comment: You can try to find them only from browser history. Recycle bin does not store deleted top navigations

Answer (score 0):

Not without a backup.  There are no auditing rules that collect that information.  With a backup you can restore as a new site and compare but that's about it.

You may be able to piece it together if you go thru the IIS logs.  For instance look at all homepage requests that direct to another page.  If you have a group of requests that go to the same page - but your current page doesn't have a direct link to it, than you probably have a good candidate for the missing item.  It can't show specifics but I can't think of any way to closer to that data, as the information simply doesn't exist.